# How can I rename filename with modified date and number count with Exiftool? (Mac)

Tags: exiftool

Trying to switch to Exiftool from jhead to rename more filetypes other than jpg & jpeg.

Whats the script for exiftool to convert from jhead:

```
jhead -n"%Y_%m_%d-newname-%04i" *.jpg
```

output: 2019_10_05-newname-0001.jpg

*.jpg as multiple files

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Related, but not dupe: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112076/11924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jhead's `-n` option appears to read the `DateTimeOriginal` tag for the timestamp so you would be doing a tag copy from `DateTimeOriginal` to `Filename`. You would use the [`-d` (dateFormat) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#d-FMT--dateFormat) to format the timestamp to your pattern and exiftool uses about the same format as JHead (see [here](https://exiftool.org/filename.html#codes) for exiftool date formatting variables).

Exiftool has the `FileSequence` tag that will holds the file count.  In order to pad that out to four places, you have to use the [Advanced formatting feature](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#Advanced-formatting-feature) and a bit of perl code.

The end result would be something like this:
Windows:
`exiftool -d "%Y_%m_%d" "-Filename<${DateTimeOriginal}-newname-${FileSequence;$_=sprintf('%04d', $_ )}.%e" <FilesOrDirs>`

Mac/Linux:
`exiftool -d '%Y_%m_%d' '-Filename<${DateTimeOriginal}-newname-${FileSequence;$_=sprintf("%04d", $_ )}.%e' <FilesOrDirs>`

Replace `Filename` with `Testname` to test the command without actually renaming any files.  Swap single/double quotes if running Mac/Linux to avoid bash interpreting parts of the command as variables.  Add [`-r` (recurse) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Thankyou, I tried your script and used the Testname on a jpg file, output gave: “Warning: syntax error for ‘FileSequence’ - /Dir/.../.../image.jpg” - “/Users/name/Desktop/Folder’ —> ‘2010_04_25-Newname-12.jpg”

Comment: Using MacOS, I also changed the quotes from double to single.

Comment: Swap all quotes.  Change all single quotes to double and all double quotes to single.  Make sure you're not using Fancy Quotes  ❝ ❞ ❛ ❜ because some macs are set up to automatically "help" by changing regular quotes into fancy quotes.

Comment: Thanks It worked, I edited your original comment to include MacOS.

Comment: Now Im renaming a MP4 file, it gave an error output: `Warning: [minor] The ExtractEmbedded option may find more tags in the movie data - /User/name/Pictures/Videos/Vid001.MP4` `Warning: No writable tags set from /User/name/Pictures/Videos/Vid001.MP4`

Comment: Video files use different tags compared to image files.  I'd suggest using `CreateDate` for those.  If that doesn't work, run `exiftool -s FILE.mp4` to see the tags in the file and pick one that would work for you.

Comment: Regarding quotes in Windows `cmd` shell, see: [Escape double quotes in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7760545/1123413) ([so])

Comment: @StarGeek I used TrackCreateDate and it worked :-) Thanks

Comment: Hi @StarGeek , This is off topic to this particular question, but I’ll remove once answered. I’m having problems with the Jhead tool, the output of renaming includes quotation marks like this “2003_05_23-foobar-0007”.jpg using this command `jhead -n"%Y_%m_%d-newname-%04i" *.jpg` .It has worked fine a couple weeks ago, I’m not sure whats causing this. Can Exiftool replace quotation marks by removing it for affected files. Also Exiftool is unable to find the Directory of a folder when executing the command shown in this post. I’m thinking macOS file permissions is causing it from a recent update

Comment: Make sure you're using regular quotes in your command.  Your example filename has Fancy Quotes/Smart Quotes (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269116/how-to-stop-note-to-stop-auto-convert-double-qoute-to-inverted-comma)). Try this to remove them with exiftool `exiftool -r '-Filename<${Filename;s/“|”//g}' /path/to/files/`  Make sure the quotes don't get replaced with the Smart Quotes when you type that in.

Comment: I’ll try again, I did copy and pasted it into Terminal before. Thanks.